# como puedo posicionar el puntero del cursor adelante del texto en el siguiente script

Tags: javascript

El problema es que el cursor no se posiciona al frente del texto, si no que se regresa al principio. con el evento 'focus' no sucede eso, pero lo quiero que funcione con el evento 'keyup'

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector('#textarea')

function funcion()
{
  textarea.innerHTML = textarea.innerText.replace(/@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/gi, '<a href="https://www.dominio.com/?user=$&">$&</a>')
}

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', funcion)
```

```html
<div id="textarea" contenteditable="true" style="height: 100px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #000"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("textarea").focus();
```

agregale este codigo deberia andar cualquier cosa no dudes en consultar

Answer (score 0):

Mira esta opción agregando una función que mantenga el cursor en posición después de agregarle el texto al div, esta pertenece a esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513329/set-cursor-to-the-end-of-contenteditable-div)

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector('#textarea')

function funcion()
{
  textarea.innerHTML = textarea.innerText.replace(/@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/gi, '<a href="https://www.dominio.com/?user=$&">$&</a>')
  setCursorToEnd(textarea)
}

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', funcion)

function setCursorToEnd(ele)
  {
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(ele, 1);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    ele.focus();
  }
```

```html
<div id="textarea" contenteditable="true" style="height: 100px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #000"></div>
```